# Recursion code not working properly

Tags: java, recursion

if i remove the comment the code is working fine and if i comment the above lines which are commentd i get an error

```
package TEST;

class Fact {
    // this is a recursive method
    int fact(int n) {

        // if (n == 1)
        // return 1;
        int result = fact(n - 1) * n;
        return result;

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Fact f = new Fact();
        System.out.println("Factorial of 7 is " + f.fact(5));
        System.out.println("Factorial of 4 is " + f.fact(4));
        System.out.println("Factorial of 5 is " + f.fact(5));
    }
}

if i remove the comment the code is working fine and if i comment the above lines which are commentd i get an error
```

Answer (score 1):

every recursive method must has an exit point, otherwise it run in an infinity loop and doesn't stop never. so your stack be full and you get a `Stackoverflow` error. see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion for more.

a pretty good example for exit point is ‍`spinning top` in [Inception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inception). if the top stop, Cobb realize that the world is real and if not he is in a dream...

Comment: so wats the problem in the code if i commentd the (if n==1) statement

Answer (score 1):

The are two conditions for writing a recursive program.
1. The method calling itself
2. Termination Condition

When u comment the

`// if (n == 1)
        // return 1;`

Your code does not know when to terminate and  goes into infinite loop hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct recursive method:

```
int fact (int n)
{
    if (n <= 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    return n * fact (n - 1);
}
```

In your code you are missing the base case, so it will never stop repeating the method.

Comment: Actually, you don't even need the `else` for it to work properly.